# Can I maintain hydration after updating an object with Propel?

Tags: php, propel

If I fetch an object like so:

```
$q = OrderReturnQuery::create()
    ->joinWith('Type')
    ->joinWith('Status')
    ->useStatusQuery()
        ->joinWith('Email')
        ->endUse()
    ->joinWith('Priority');
$object = $q->findPk(1);
var_dump($object->toArray(TableMap::TYPE_PHPNAME, true, [], true));
```

This is the output I get:

```
array (size=14)
  'Id' => int 1
  'TypeId' => int 3
  'StatusId' => int 2
  'PriorityId' => int 1
  'OrderId' => int 234567
  'CustomerId' => int 5
  'Initiated' => string '2016-03-02T01:11:12+00:00' (length=25)
  'Initiator' => int 2
  'FreePostageLabel' => boolean true
  'LostInPost' => boolean false
  'SuppressEmail' => boolean true
  'Type' => 
    array (size=4)
      'Id' => int 3
      'Title' => string 'title 3' (length=7)
      'Priority' => int 3
      'OrderReturns' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '*RECURSION*' (length=11)
  'Status' => 
    array (size=6)
      'Id' => int 2
      'EmailId' => int 2
      'Title' => string 'title 2' (length=7)
      'Priority' => int 2
      'Email' => 
        array (size=5)
          'Id' => int 2
          'Subject' => string 'subject 2' (length=9)
          'Plaintext' => string 'plain text 2' (length=12)
          'Html' => string 'html 2' (length=6)
          'Statuses' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '*RECURSION*' (length=11)
      'OrderReturns' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '*RECURSION*' (length=11)
  'Priority' => 
    array (size=4)
      'Id' => int 1
      'Title' => string 'title 1' (length=7)
      'Priority' => int 1
      'OrderReturns' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '*RECURSION*' (length=11)
```

Now if I modify the original code to change a value before dumping:

```
$object = $q->findPk(1);¬
$object->setStatusId(5);
```

The resulting output doesn't include the `Status` element, only the 'StatusId'. I can of course get this back with `$object->getStatus()` before using `toArray()` but is there a way to do this generically?

I was wondering if there's a way to check if a value is a foreign key so that if it is I can automatically get `getWhatevers()` after that value is set, instead of hard-coding them. Or maybe there's a better way?

My other option is to override `toArray` but the scope for errors and amount of maintenance as a database changes here would have to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling the toArray method the fourth parameter can be set to true in order to make the model retrieve the related objects

```
$object->toArray(TableMap:: TYPE_PHPNAME, true, [], true);
```

Edit:
As @DarkBee noted in the comments you where already calling the `toArray` with the correct parameters, so why you aren't getting the related objects in your array representation?
The answer probably resides in this step of your code

```
$object->setStatusId(5)
```

You're actually updating your object without updating the database related record, by doing this Propel isn't able to retrieve the correct related object, to avoid this behavior you can set the full Status object instead of the sole id, eg:

```
$object->setStatus(StatusQuery::create()->findPk(5));
```

By doing this you will have the correct Status object information in your array representation, be careful that this (as already said), probably, doesn't reflect the database state.